Use OutputCacheAttribute to create opt-out of cached responses in .Net 8 ASP.NET Web API
In implementing the newest version of .Net's response caching middleware, we need to make a policy that allows callers to bypass cached responses if they send a specific header key.
For the sake of simplicity, key values of "bypass-cache" = "true" are sufficient for an example.
// Program.cs

  // ...contents omitted from brevity.

  builder.Services.AddOutputCache(o =>
  {
    // Allow callers to bypass the cache with a specific header value.
    o.AddBasePolicy(o => 
      o.With(r => r.HttpContext.Request.Headers["bypass-cache"] == "true")
      .NoCache()
    );
  });

  // ...contents omitted from brevity.

  // I have experimented with moving this up and down to see if the order of middleware impacted it.
  app.UseOutputCache(); 

  // ...contents omitted from brevity.


The controllers are decorated with the OutputCacheAttribute
  [HttpGet]
  [OutputCache]
  public async Task<IActionResult> ReadById(int id)
  {
    // Even when the value of this `check` is true, the policy is ignored !
    var check = HttpContext.Request.Headers["bypass-cache"] == "true";

    var request = new ReadCrudByIdRequest(id);
    var result = await _mediator.Send(request);
    return Ok(result);
  }

Post man is being used to manually this endpoint.  As mentioned in the comment, I can see in the controller when the value is true or false, but it does not have any impact on the Policy.  I have also attempted creating an explicitly named policy and labeling the endpoint with [OutputCache(PolicyName = "bypass-cache")] but the result is the same.
Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

UPDATE
builder.Services.AddOutputCache(o =>
{
    o.AddBasePolicy(builder => builder.Cache());

    o.AddPolicy("bypass-cache", o =>
      o.With(r => r.HttpContext.Request.Headers["bypass-cache"] == "true")
          .NoCache()
        );
});

[HttpGet("test")]
[OutputCache(PolicyName = "bypass-cache")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ReadById(int id)
{
    return Ok(id);
}


You should implement this feature like below.
builder.Services.AddOutputCache(o =>
{
    o.AddBasePolicy(builder => builder.NoCache());

    o.AddPolicy("cache", o =>
        o.With(r => r.HttpContext.Request.Headers["cache"] == "true")
            .Expire(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
        );
});

And use it.
[HttpGet("test")]
[OutputCache(PolicyName = "cache")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ReadById(int id)
{
        
    return Ok(id);
}


The intent is for an "opt-out" option.  What I don't want is, lazy clients that don't add the proper header info to be able to bypass the cache by default.  Thank for the contribution, though!  I edited the question title to be more explicit.

Hi @ScumSprocket Updated. Please check it.

Hi @ScumSprocket , may I know if my updated answer is useful or not ?
